# How to change alignment value of a text box field using PDFBox 2.0.21 (Fillable form)

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdf-form

I would like to change the text box property values of alignment property using pdf box.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try quadding

```
textBox.setQ(PDVariableText.QUADDING_CENTERED);
```